# can we move listview from sandbox to production in salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I am new to salesforce development and I encountered one problem while moving my object and related thing to production. Can we move listview from sandbox to production? because I can't see any option in Eclipse IDE to select or in changeset. May be I am overlooking something. Please help...

Answer (score 0):

This answer will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/578763/356042

You can do it by using [force.com migration tool](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Migration_Tool)